# Confusion of bounded set

Tags: general-topology

Just wondering is that true we need a metic to define a bounded set? i.e. a bounded set only exists in metric space? Thanks!

Comment: There are ordered non-metrizable spaces.

Comment: Good question. In general topological space does not require metric. But the question if we can define bounded set. I believe, bounded set is not a topological term, so the question if we can find reasonable definition for topological sets without metric

Comment: Consider [bornological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space). Metric boundedness, linear-space boundedness and order boundedness can all be seen as special cases of this general notion. So there can be many ways to define a "bounded" set.

Answer (score 1):

The best other example I could think of is the one in ordered set. But I am not sure we can get rid of a metric :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set#Boundedness_in_order_theory

EDIT: If it can help you, I'd like to mention that we can define compactness without metric, for instance by using filters in a topological space (analogous to sequences) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)

Answer (score 1):

In a topological vector space, a set $A$ is (von Neumann) bounded if for every neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ there exists $c>0$ with $A \subseteq c U$.

Answer (score 0):

A subset A of a metric space is bounded when
exists x in space, real r with A subset B(x,r).

A subset A of a topological space is bounded when
exists compact K with A subset K.

A subset A of an order <= is bounded when
exists a,b with a <= A <= b (for all x in A, a <= x <= b).

Comment: Do you know if any of those definitions are compatible with any of the others (or even if one implies another)?

Comment: As much as @BrianMoehring, brick laying, sheet metal fabrication and clothing manufacturing does.